# Is there a way to cut and paste or clone CSS from one element to another using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a situation where I'm wrapping an image with a span and I want to remove all the CSS from the image and apply it to the span. Is there a way to do this with JQuery?

JQuery:

```
$(img).wrap('<span />');
```

Style Sheet:

```
img { border: 5px solid red; padding: 10px; … needs to allow for anything }
```

I would like to do this with out editing the HTML or CSS. I need a way to truly remove the CSS from one element and place it on another.

Comment: yes. But if we can't see what you're starting with and what you want to finish with, you won't get the best solution.  Please post some code.

Comment: what do you mean by style, is it inline, wrapped in class or coming from stylesheet?

Comment: I don't believe you can do what you want, the `img` style will be applied to an `<img>` unless that tag negates or overrides the style inside itself.  You could however change that style to be `img.myClass` and have a removable class on that `<img>`...barring that, I don't think there's a solution for removing default browser behavior here.

Answer (score 1):

There's also toggleClass(), which simply applies the class if it is not already on the element, and removes it if it is.

```
$("#imageIDHere,#otherThing").toggleClass("theClass");
```

I have a feeling, looking at your question, that you're planning for some kind of dynamic CSS structure.  You can absolutely change classes, CSS selectors and their properties dynamically, using things like this [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/changecss).  However, doing this without any class structure at all or overarching system is most likely setting you up for a lot of headaches down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just apply your CSS class to the span (and remove from the image)?

See [.addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [.removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Comment: I'm not using a class to apply the CSS to the image. I could do what your saying but it is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

```
/*CSS*/
.style{border:solid 1px red;}

/*JQuery*/

$("#imageIDHere").removeClass("style");
$("#spanIDHere").addClass("style");

/*or*/

$("#imageIDHere").removeClass("style").parent().addClass("style"); //assuming the span is the parent of the image
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **[`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)** and **[`removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)** to remove the style depening on your requirement.

**Examples:**

```
$('selector').removeClass('some_class'); // this removes some_class
$('selector').removeClass(); // this removes all classes
$('selector').removeAttr('class'); // this removes inline classes
$('selector').removeAttr('style'); // this removes inline styling
$('selector').removeAttr('id'); // this removes id styling
```

Comment: @Nick Craver: Forgot about that (funny) altogether. Thanks man :)

Comment: Will $('selector').removeClass(); remove all styles or only style applied with a class?

Comment: @Jared Christensen: As the name suggests, it will remove class styling.

Comment: @Jared - It will only remove what's in `style=""` directly on the element though, not from your stylesheet, which seems to be what you're after.